# Tried to compile contract using hardhat but got error:- Error: The specified module could not be found

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, npm, solidity, hardhat

```
Error: The specified module could not be found.
\\?\C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Hardhat\node_modules\@nomicfoundation\solidity-analyzer-win32-x64-msvc\solidity-analyzer.win32-x64-msvc.node      
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1210:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Hardhat\node_modules\@nomicfoundation\solidity-analyzer\index.js:69:29)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}
```

Tried to compile but didnt get any result.It countain the specified modules but throws error.

Comment: Can you share the file structure?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Drag that specified module into that folder where all the other files are kept. Do the same with other modules till all the files required for the project are not under one folder.
This might help.
Thank You.